# Generators of families of langauges?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

From [Wikipedia's definition of regular langauges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition)

> The collection of regular languages over an alphabet $Σ$ is defined
>   recursively as follows:
>
> - The empty language $Ø$ is a regular language.
> - For each $a ∈ Σ$, the language $\{a\}$ is a regular language.
> - If $A$ and $B$ are regular languages, then $A \cup B$ (union), $A • B$ (concatenation), and $A^*$ (Kleene star) are regular languages.
> - No other languages over$ Σ$ are regular.

The regular languages also form a [(full) AFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages).

Parallel to [the concept of generator for a sigma algebra](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aSigma-Algebra_Generated_by_Collection_of_Subsets), do the regular languages form the minimal  (full) AFL (or (full) semi-AFL, full trio, trio, ...)  that contains the empty language, and  $\{a\}, a ∈ Σ$? In other words, are the minimal  (full) AFL (or (full) semi-AFL, [full trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trio_%28formal_languages%29), trio, ...) generated by the empty language, and  $\{a\}, a ∈ Σ$ exactly the regular langauges?

Comment: Quoting from Hopcroft/Ullman (not the subsequent Hopcroft/Motwani/Ullman, which omits the discussion), "... the regular sets are the smallest full trio. They are also a full AFL and therefore the smallest full AFL. The $\epsilon$-free regular sets are the smallest AFL, as well as the smallest trio." (But you probably already knew that.)

Comment: Thanks, @Rick. I didn't. What about context free langauges, context-sensitive langauges, recursive langauges, and recursively enumerable langauges?

Comment: Continuing, H/U state that CFL's are full AFL's as are r.e languages. The CSL's are an AFL, but not a full AFL. In my annotations to my copy of H/U, I have that recursive languages are trios, but nothing else (though my marginalia didn't include a proof and it's been years since I looked at this stuff)..

Comment: @RickDecker: Ha, had I read that before starting to compose my answer, I could have saved me some trouble!

Comment: @Rick: Not saying smallest ... that contains ...?

Comment: @Raphael. Perhaps, but your answer was (as usual) very good.

Comment: @Rick: How are  ϵ-free regular sets defined?

Comment: @Tim: Just like in my answer, I suppose; languages that don't contain $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @RickDecker: Why, thanks! I'd have gotten into bed earlier, though, had I not first tried to prove FIN to be a trio and then REG to be the smallest founded trio. ;)

Comment: @Raphael: Thanks. Are ϵ-free regular languages defined as those regular languages that do not contain the empty string? Is ϵ the empty string, or the empty language?

Comment: @Tim: $\varepsilon$ usually denotes the empty string. (Did you overreach just a little bit with your question? O.o) Note that $\emptyset \neq \{\varepsilon\}$. (A student I taught one called the latter the "almost empty language".)

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of notation, let's call a family of languages $\mathcal{L}$ that contains

1. the empty set $\emptyset$ and
2. all singleton sets $\{a\}$, $a$ some symbol,

a *founded* family, and

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathcal{L}_+ = \{ L \in \mathcal{L} \mid \varepsilon \not\in L\}$.

Let $L \in \mathrm{REG}_+$ arbitrary. We will construct $L$ from only the empty and singleton sets using the trio operations

- $\varepsilon$-free homomorphism,
- inverse homomorphism and
- intersection with regular languages,

thus proving that (1) all founded trios also contain $\mathrm{REG}_+$. Furthermore, (2) $\mathrm{REG}_+$ it is a founded trio itself. Therefore, we have shown that $\mathrm{REG}_+$ is the minimal founded trio.

---

1. It suffices to show that $\Sigma^+ \supset L$ is contained in every founded trio $\mathcal{T}$; the rest is trivial by $L = \Sigma^+ \cap L \in \mathrm{REG}_+$.

   We define for any alphabet $\Sigma$ a marked copy $\hat{\Sigma} = \{ \hat{a} \mid a \in \Sigma \}$ and two homomorphisms $h,g : \Sigma \cup \hat{\Sigma} \to \Sigma^*$ by

   $\qquad\displaystyle 
     h(a) = \begin{cases}
              a &, a \in \Sigma \\
              \varepsilon &, a \in \hat{\Sigma}
            \end{cases}
   $

   and

   $\qquad\displaystyle 
     g(a) = \begin{cases}
              b &, a = b \in \Sigma \\
              b &, a = \hat{b} \in \hat{\Sigma}
            \end{cases}
   $.

   Now consider

   $\qquad\displaystyle L' = \Sigma \hat{\Sigma}^*$.

   By noting that

   - $\Sigma = h(L') \iff h^{-1}(\Sigma) = L'$,
   - $g(L') = \Sigma^+$ and
   - $g$ is $\varepsilon$-free,

   we obtain from the trio closure properties that

   $\qquad\displaystyle \Sigma \in \mathcal{T} \implies \Sigma^+ \in \mathcal{T}$.

   But since $\Sigma$ is the pre-image of every $\{a\} \subseteq \Sigma$ with suitable constant homomorphism $h_a(b) = a$ we have $\Sigma \in \mathcal{T}$ by foundedness and closure under inverse homomorphism.
2. We check the conditions of a founded trio for $\mathrm{REG}_+$:

   - Closure under $\varepsilon$-free homomorphism: clear since $\mathrm{REG}$ has this property and no such homomorphism can generate $\varepsilon$ from an $\varepsilon$-free language.
   - Closure under inverse homomorphism: clear since $\mathrm{REG}$ has this property and the image of $\varepsilon$ is always $\varepsilon$.
   - Closure against intersection with regular languages: clear by def.
   - Foundedness: clear by def; all required sets are regular and don't contain the empty word..

---

$\mathrm{REG}$ actually *is* the minimal "founded" trio if you add $\{\varepsilon\}$ to the base; a similar proof goes through.

Furthermore, $\mathrm{REG}_+$ is *not* a full trio (cone) because of it's lack of empty words. We extend above proof by noting that containment of $\mathrm{REG}_+$ now implies containment of $\mathrm{REG}$ (any regular language $L$ is the image of $\hat{a}L \in \mathrm{REG}_+$ by a homomorphism that deletes only $\hat{a}$). Since $\mathrm{REG}$ is itself a cone it is also the minimal cone.

---

The properties extend to (semi-)AFLs, i.e. $\mathrm{REG}_+$ is the minimal (semi-)AFL and $\mathrm{REG}$ is the minimal full (semi-)AFL.